# Testing-library unable to find rc-menu

Tags: antd, react-testing-library, react-component, testing-library

I'm trying to implement integration tests on our React frontend which uses Ant design. Whenever we create a table, we add an action column in which we have a [Menu and Menu Items](https://ant.design/components/menu/) to perform certain actions.
However, I seem unable to find the correct button in the menu item when using react-testing-library. The menu Ant design uses is rc-menu and I believe it renders outside of the rendered component.
Reading the testing-library documentation, I've tried using baseElement and queryByRole to get the correct DOM element, but it doesn't find anything.
Here's an example of what I'm trying to do. It's all async since the table has to wait on certain data before it gets filled in, just an FYI.

[Tried it on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-butterfly-r3dity?file=/Table.component.spec.js)

```
const row = await screen.findByRole('row', {
    name: /test/i
  })

const menu = await within(row).findByRole('menu')
fireEvent.mouseDown(menu)
expect(queryByRole('button', { name: /delete/i })).toBeDisabled()
```

[the menu being opened with the delete action as menu item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQWoq.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added a sandbox url

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue testing antd + rc-menu component. Looks like the issue is related to delayed popup rendering. Here is an example how I solved it:

```
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    const { queryByTestId, getByText } = renderMyComponent();
    const nav = await waitFor(() => getByText("My Menu item text"));
    act(() => {
      fireEvent.mouseEnter(nav);
      jest.runAllTimers(); // ! <- this was a trick !
    });
    jest.useRealTimers();
    expect(queryByTestId("submenu-item-test-id")).toBeTruthy();
```